# Expected number of times of choosing a word out of a given vocabulary when words are grouped

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Two players (player C and player G) are playing a (modified) word guessing game. Both players share the same vocabulary $V$ and words in $V$ are grouped into $K$ bins, denoted as $b_1$, $b_2$, ..., $b_{K}$. Furthermore, we know that $b_{i} \subset V$ and $\cup_{i=1}^{K} b_i = V$. Note here we do not have $b_i \cap b_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$.

The game protocol is described as follows:

1. Player C uniformly chooses a word $w$ from the vocabulary $V$. Player G does not know which word $w$ is.
2. Player G chooses one bin and asks Player C whether his/her chosen word $w$ is in the bin. If it is, the game ends. Otherwise, Player G will choose another bin.

**Questions**: What is the best bin choosing order and what is the expected number of times of choosing the bin, according to the best possible order?

**Example:**

Suppose we have a vocabulary consisting of ten words $V = \{w_1, w_2, ..., w_{10} \}$ and three bins $b_1 = \{w_1, w_2, ..., w_5\}$, $b_2 = \{w_6, w_7 \}$, and $b_3 = \{w_8, w_9, w_{10} \}$.

One possible bin choosing order is $b_1 \rightarrow b_3 \rightarrow b_2$ and the expected number of times of choosing the bin is $\frac{1}{2}*1 + \frac{1}{2}*\frac{3}{5}*2 + \frac{1}{2}*\frac{2}{5}*\frac{2}{2}*3 = 1.7$. I suspect this is the best bin choosing order but how can we prove this result?

Thanks.

**Note**

A related question (which has additional non-overlapping constraints on the bins) is asked in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326236/expected-number-of-times-of-choosing-a-word-out-of-a-given-vocabulary-when-words) and in its comment, the user @DavidG.Stork gives a good answer (an intuitive proof of best ordering) for the case when those bins have no overlap.

Comment: When you say "uniformly chooses" do you mean "uniformly at random chooses"? If so, it's not much of a game.

Comment: I do mean "uniformly at random chooses". It is not really a game from the "game theory" point of view. I use the term "game" to describe the interaction protocol among two players. Maybe I should use another term.

Comment: No problem. Your use of the term "game" just had me thinking about strategies for each player, when in fact only one "player" can be said to have a strategy here. And the best strategy is not actually obvious. If the bins were $b_1 = \{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$, $b_2 = \{1,2,3,7,8 \}$ and $b_3 = \{4,5,6,9,10 \}$, the "obvious" choice of selecting bin $b_1$ first would not be correct.

Comment: Simulposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326236/expected-number-of-times-of-choosing-a-word-out-of-a-given-vocabulary-when-words with no notice to either site.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Is there some rule against this? The OP is a new contributor. I've been here 3 years and if such a rule exists, I have never heard of it.

Comment: @Jens, when you're hungry, do you order pizza from several different pizzerias at a time, or just from one?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: I ask everyone I know or can think of if they can satisfy my hunger. I could now say "you didn't answer my question", but it would distract from the question at hand. Do you have a relevant input to it?

Comment: @Jens, what do you do when three delivery boys show up at your door with pizzas for you? Do you tell two of them, sorry that I've wasted your time, but I already got the pizza from the first guy?

Comment: @Jens, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9337/is-cross-posted-forbidden-discouraged-on-stack-exchange-sites-if-so-why and many more.

Comment: @Gerry I asked if there was a rule against it and you have so far not answered. I also asked if you had relevant input to the OP and you have not provided any. This is my last comment to you here.

Comment: @Jens, oh, goody, I get the last word! Jens, there's no explicit rule against having your cat type all your posts to m.se, but try it and see how far you get. And then please, please read the discussions I linked, and the ones linked to them, to see what the consensus opinion is on simulposting, and the supporting reasons.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, To clarify, I posted the initial question in MO and one person quickly commented that the question is not "research-level" question and thus should be posted in m.se. I took his/her suggestion and posted it here. I did not see any rule against this and there was no indication from the system that this is wrong behavior. I read your posts and it seems there is such agreement (at least recognized in some communities).

Comment: @GerryMyerson. I will add a link to either site but keep the question in both sites without deleting them for two reasons. First, the question descriptions are somewhat different (the one in MO has additional non-overlapping constraint the OP here has no such constraint). Second and more importantly, there is an answer in MO (for the problem with non-overlapping constraint) which I think is good and can benefit contributors in both sites.

Comment: @MickeyJ.Shen - Thanks for the explanation and adding the cross link.  You were new and didn't know, and it was not exactly a rule (as far as I know), and once you found out you corrected it.  So it's all good IMHO.  Ironically, the non-overlap case is trivial and you posted to MO, but the overlap case might actually be hard and you posted it here.  :)  But I can't judge whether it's hard enough to be stackoverflow worthy.  Anyway now that you've posted the overlap version here, let us MSE folks have a crack at it for a while first.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but too long for a comment.

For a given ordering of bins, lets say $a_{1}, a_{2}, ..., a_{K}$ (which is a permutation of the $b_i$'s), let $f(w)$ be the discovery time for word $w$.  Then $f(w) = j$, i.e. it  will be discovered during the $j$th bin, iff $w \in c_j$ where $c_j = a_{j} - \bigcup^{j-1}_{i=1} a_i$.  I.e. $c_j$ are the new words introduced by bin $a_j$.

To calculate the expected number of turns, sum up all the discovery times $f(w)$ and then divide by the number of words.  So the expected number is minimized when $\sum_{w \in V} f(w)$ is minimized.

In the OP's original example all $b_i$'s are disjoint, so it's pretty clear that $\sum_{w \in V} f(w)$ is minimized when you assign the most number of them as $1$s, then the next-most number of them as $2$s, etc.  In this example the expected number of turns $= {5\times 1 + 3 \times 2 + 2 \times 3 \over 10} = 1.7$.

When the $b_i$'s are not disjoint, then as shown by the excellent example of @Jens in the comments, the greedy strategy can be suboptimal - it assigns the numbers $1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3$ for a total of $16$ when the optimal strategy assigns the numbers $1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2$ for a total of $15$.

Comment: Thanks for the complement! One might think the way forward was to find the smallest subset of bins which together contain all the words, but consider the following example: $b_1 = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \}$, $b_2 = \{1,2,3, 8\}$, $b_3 = \{4,5,9 \}$, $b_4 = \{6,7,10 \}$. In this case, selecting $b_1$ first is actually the right strategy.

Comment: @Jens I had the exact same conjecture as yours and then also came up with a counterexample: $\{1,2,3,4,5\}, \{6,7,8,9,10\},\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9\}$ where $8 \times 1 + 2 + 3 = 13 < 15$.  I'm quite curious what the answer is.  Now that the first two obvious strategies don't work, I wonder if it might actually be NP complete.